# trying to update records in mysql database (php)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

i've been browsing StackOverflow and other sites looking for other ways to do this and nothing I've tried seems to have worked.

The editscript.php seems to stop at `echo "making connection<br>";` and the database does not update, and I can't make heads or tails of why.

I'd really apprecite some advice as to where I am going wrong.

Cheers!

<<>>

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit Entry</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

echo "<a href=\"index.php\">go home, you are drunk.</a>";

$id=$_GET["id"];

//db vars
$sqlhost='localhost';
$sqluser='sqluser';
$sqlpass='sqlpass';
$sqldb='riggingregister';

// Make a MySQL Connection
$con=mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqluser,$sqlpass,$sqldb);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='$id'");

echo "<form action=\"editscript.php\" method=\"post\">";
echo "<table width=\"372\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\">";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>" . $row['id'] . "</td></tr>";
  echo "<input name=\"id\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . $row['id'] ."\" />";
  echo "<tr><td>Register</td><td><input name=\"register\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['register'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Location</td><td><input name=\"location\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['location'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Type</td><td><input name=\"type\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['type'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Capacity</td><td><input name=\"capacity\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['capacity'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Length</td><td><input name=\"length\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['length'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Qty</td><td><input name=\"qty\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['qty'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Serial#</td><td><input name=\"serial\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['serial'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Certificate#</td><td><input name=\"cert\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['cert'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Last Inspection Completed On</td><td><input name=\"lastinsp\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['lastinsp'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Last Inspection Completed By</td><td><input name=\"inspby\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['inspby'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Date introduced into service</td><td><input name=\"datein\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['datein'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Date removed from service</td><td><input name=\"dateout\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['dateout'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td>Notes</td><td><input name=\"notes\" type=\"text\" value=\"". $row['notes'] ."\"/></td></tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" value=\"Confirm Changes\" />";
echo "</form>";

mysqli_close($con);
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

<<>>

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Edit Entry (Script)</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Go Home!</a><br /><hr />";

//db vars
$sqlhost='localhost';
$sqluser='riggingregister';
$sqlpass='RIGGINGregister';
$sqldb='riggingregister';

//fetch form input
$id = $_POST['id'];
$register = $_POST['register'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$capacity = $_POST['capacity'];
$length = $_POST['length'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$serial = $_POST['serial'];
$cert = $_POST['cert'];
$lastinsp = $_POST['lastinsp'];
$inspby = $_POST['inspby'];
$datein = $_POST['datein'];
$dateout = $_POST['dateout'];
$notes = $_POST['notes'];

echo "$id<br /> $register<br /> $location<br /> $type<br /> $capacity<br /> $length<br /> $qty<br /> $serial<br /> $lastinsp<br /> $inspby<br /> $datein<br /> $dateout<br /> $notes<br /><br />";

// Make a MySQL Connection
echo "making connection<br>";
$con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqluser,$sqlpass,$sqldb) or die(mysql_error());
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//perform update query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,
                       "UPDATE register SET 
                        register=?, 
                        location=?, 
                        type=?, 
                        capacity=?,
                        length=?,
                        qty=?,
                        serial=?,
                        cert=?,
                        lastinsp=?,
                        inspby=?,
                        datein=?,
                        dateout=?,
                        notes=?
                        WHERE id=?") or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssiiisssssssi',
                       $register, $location, $type, $capacity, $length, $qty, $serial, $cert, $lastinsp, $inspby, $datein, $dateout, $notes, $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Home</a>";

//close connection to db
mysqli_close();

?> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: The argument to `mysql_error()` is the database connection, not a string.

Comment: You're also missing the first argument to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: updated the question, my apologies.

Comment: Barmar, I changed as per your recomendation, but it just echos `Can't update the records:` after the 'making connections'

Comment: `$id = $_POST[id];` to `$id = $_POST['id'];` and do the same for the others, now that you've changed `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error()` @ZachFlem

Comment: updated code to current version.

Comment: This line `$con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqluser,$sqlpass,$sqldb) or die(mysql_error());` needs to be `$con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqluser,$sqlpass,$sqldb) or die(mysqli_error());` @ZachFlem that came from Barmar where he didn't change it yet as I [`commented on that.`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418988/trying-to-update-records-in-mysql-database-php#comment34090192_22419062) it's still `or die(mysql_error());` where it needs to be `or die(mysqli_error());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` functions, you can't do that. You're also not passing the connection object to the `mysqli` functions. You should use parametrized queries instead of variable substitution.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($sqlhost,$sqluser,$sqlpass,$sqldb) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());

//perform update query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,
                       "UPDATE register SET 
                        register=?, 
                        location=?, 
                        type=?, 
                        capacity=?,
                        length=?,
                        qty=?,
                        serial=?,
                        cert=?,
                        lastinsp=?,
                        inspby=?,
                        datein=?,
                        dateout=?,
                        notes=?
                        WHERE id=?") or die(mysqli_error($con));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssiiisssssssi',
                       $register, $location, $type, $capacity, $length, $qty, $serial, $cert, $lastinsp, $inspby, $datein, $dateout, $notes, $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
//echo "update successful! YAY!<br />";
echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Home</a>";

//close connection to db
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: changed as per suggestions, still same result as before

Comment: Sorry, I left `$con` out of `mysqli_prepare()`, try it now.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled -- that error should have caused a PHP error to be printed.

Comment: @Barmar Your answer still contains `or die(mysql_error());` - 1st line.

Comment: this one seems to have fixed things, thanks folks.  I have some reading to do to work out exactly what is happening now though!

Comment: This answer by the way @ZachFlem is based on using [`prepared statements`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`here is a good tutorial`](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452) on the subject, should you want to read up on them.

Comment: You're welcome. See my edited comment; I added a link to a tutorial on prepared statements. @ZachFlem